# How to add collation to Linq expressions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, oop

How to implement method for IQuariable like below:

```
var trash = (from a in ContextBase.db.Users
                orderby a.FirstName
                select a).ToCollatedList();
```

In a result I want to see

```
SELECT * from [User] 
ORDER BY FirstName
COLLATE SQL_SwedishStd_Pref_Cp1_CI_AS ASC
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't extend the Linq-to-Sql implementation to perform new functionality on the server.

The best you can do is a client-side implementation of collation.

Comment: Could you knowledge us know, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I would expose a view for the different collations and allow the developers to run LINQ to SQL queries against the views.