# sql search on fields containing diacritics

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, collation

I'm working at a web site search which uses Sql server 2008 express edition.

I have **'Books'** table which has a field named **'Title**' where there are titles containing romanian (latin) characters.

Well, if the user inserts a word like: 'casa' in the search field and i have a title in db like: 'test ***casă*** test' i want to show that book but:

```
select * from books where title like '%casa%'
```

will not find it...

Do you know any function which removes the diacritics when doing the select?

I know that i can solve the problem with full text searching add-on of sql server but i want to do it in a simpler way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
select * from books where title COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI like '%casa%'
```

Of course, you should choose a collation that matches yours... just change AS to AI on the end to make it "accent insensitive"

Quick example with German umlauts

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE (bar varchar(100) /*implied COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS*/)

INSERT @foo VALUES ('xxx fish yyy')
INSERT @foo VALUES ('xxx bar yyy' )
INSERT @foo VALUES ('xxx bär yyy')

select * from @foo where bar COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI like '%bar%'
select * from @foo where bar like '%bar%'
```

Comment: Also, you can change the collation for your database if you always want searches to be accent insensitive.

Comment: One more question: Do u know how to do this in linq also? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Cristian Boariu: sorry, I don't. And perhaps you can't anyway... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488249

Answer (score 6):

You need to use an accent insensitive collate clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it in linq, I think you have to remove diacritics first in the searched string and then to make a linq query... it should work...